# Time step in Hull white mean reverting model

Tags: interest, rates, mean

Specially for mean reverting processes for interest rate simulation. Is it acceptable to directly simulate the paths at say 1 month horizon without stepping through time? Please advice.

Comment: Hull White is gaussian and can be simulated directly at desired points in time (i.e. with as large time steps as one wishes). Please check the paper "Efficient and Exact Simulation of the Hull-White Model" by Ostrovski.

Comment: To add to above, some MC schemes are non-exact, so as long as you’re using an exact scheme you can do a large time step.